# Ideals of the tensor product $R\otimes_{k} S$?

Tags: commutative-algebra, tensor-products

Let $R$ and $S$ be commutative rings over a field $k$. Let $I$ be an ideal of the tensor ring $R\otimes_{k} S$. It is true that there exist ideals $I_{1}$ and $I_{2}$ of $R$ and $S$ respectively such that 
$$
I=I_{1}\otimes_{k} I_{2}? 
$$
If this is not true, are there any description of $I$? What if we don't assume commutativity of one of rings?

Answer (score 3):

The simplest example of the setup is probably

- $R = k[x]$
- $S = k[y]$
- $R \otimes_k S = k[x,y]$

and the simplest ideals of $R \otimes_k S$ are principal ideals. The first place to look for such a thing that is a counter-example would be to pick a generator that isn't obviously a product of something from $k[x]$ and something from $k[y]$.

(P.S. I think you can arrange for an $I_1$ and an $I_2$ such that the "inclusion" from $I_1 \otimes_k I_2$ to $R \otimes_k S$ isn't monic, so really it isn't an ideal)

Comment: $(x+y)$ works. I am sorry that this is too easy question. I should have thought more. This example shows that there is no good description of ideals of $R\otimes S$, I think.

Comment: Dear Hurkyl, the morphism $I_1 \otimes_k I_2 \to R \otimes_k S$ is injective because all modules over a field are flat.

Comment: @Pooya Well, it is not possible to completely characterise prime ideals of the tensor products in terms of prime ideals of each of the factors. However, [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1629695/constructing-prime-ideal-of-tensor-product-from-two-prime-ideals) might help. From what I understand, you can think of $\operatorname{Spec} (A\otimes B)$ as small collections of ideals indexed by pairs $(p,q)$, $p\in \operatorname{Spec} A$, $q\in \operatorname{Spec} B$, corresponding to $\operatorname{Spec} (k(p)\otimes k(q))$.